# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" (Error when running `sbt test`)

Tags: java, scala, testing, playframework-2.3

On my local Mac OS (Mountain Lion), I have been running `sbt test` just fine and the tests compiled/passed with Play 2.3.x, Scala (2.10.x). Java version on my local was "1.8.0_131".

After re-imaging my Mac OS X(10.12.3), I started getting the very strange error when running "sbt test" for the same codebase (Play, Scala, Java versions still the same).

Probably, this might not be to do with my Mac upgrade but that is the only variable (change) I could think of right now.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a quick pointer on probable causes of this?

Error stack trace looks something like

```
[error]    NumberFormatException: : For input string: ""  (ProxyUtils.java:159)
[error] com.ning.http.util.ProxyUtils.createProxyServerSelector(ProxyUtils.java:159)
[error] com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder.build(AsyncHttpClientConfig.java:1132)
[error] play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder.build(NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder.scala:37)
[error] play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSAPI.buildAsyncClientConfig(NingWS.scala:563)
[error] play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSAPI.newClient(NingWS.scala:520)
[error] play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSAPI$$anonfun$client$1.apply(NingWS.scala:543)
[error] play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSAPI$$anonfun$client$1.apply(NingWS.scala:540)
[error] play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSAPI.client(NingWS.scala:538)
[error] play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSAPI.url(NingWS.scala:553)
[error] play.api.libs.ws.WS$.url(WS.scala:129)
```

Comment: I know I'm being vague to some extent (intentionally) and I have got an answer.

It is a system proxy that is set (on my machine) which is used by a third-party library (somehow) and that caused this error. 

(I must admit it is a kind of vague answer again, I must admit, but that is all I can say here.)

Answer (score 2):

> I would really appreciate if someone could give me a quick pointer on the cause of this?

You just need to look at the stack trace. It can give you a 'pointer' of the cause.

For instance, here, the cause is indicated in the message of the exception, which is :

> For input string: ""

Which indicates that a line of code tried to parse a string containing nothing, and threw an exception to indicate a failed conversion from string to a number

The probable cause of this is some data that the application retrived somewhere, and was changed after the re-imaging of the computer. Generally, a way to correct that **might** be to re-install the app

Comment: I was not being clear enough. Updated the question description. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

As @HatsuPointerKun is already stating. You are still not providing enough information.

But maybe this helps. It seems like, that in some point of your code base the WebApplication sends a Request over Play WS. 
Because it is having trouble with the URL I assume that there is some port issue (I may lie wrong).

Thats the furthest it can go with the provided information. I can just suggest you to debug your code at the point the Stacktrace is showing you and debug the code to see which value is causing the problem. And you can get a deeper look on the stack and see where your component is using it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know issue had been resolve. Pasting here my solution in case someone else runs into the same issue.

I've seen this error before it happened in my case because the project was using a buildnumber that was supposed to be set in buildinfo.properties. It was set to empty hence the sbt compile error after setting buildnumber the error went away

```
cat buildinfo.properties 
#Tue Nov 24 21:12:02 EST 2020
buildnumber=

  [info] Set current project to dummy-project (in build file:/home/mly/workspace/dummy-project)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""                                   
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:229)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
        at sbtbuildinfo.BuildInfoPlugin$.readProp$1(BuildInfoPlugin.scala:33)
        at sbtbuildinfo.BuildInfoPlugin$.buildNumberTask(BuildInfoPlugin.scala:39)
        at sbtbuildinfo.BuildInfoPlugin$$anonfun$buildInfoDefaultSettings$5.apply(BuildInfoPlugin.scala:89)
        at sbtbuildinfo.BuildInfoPlugin$$anonfun$buildInfoDefaultSettings$5.apply(BuildInfoPlugin.scala:89)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (dummy-project/*:buildInfoBuildNumber) java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

When buildnumber set compilation error will disappear

```
cat buildinfo.properties 
#Tue Nov 24 21:12:02 EST 2020
buildnumber=123
```