# Java Playframework SBT Compile Exception - Unexpected exception[NumberFormatException: For input string: " "]

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I have been having this issue ever since my system got powered down without a warning. On starting my machine and launched my Ide to start the project, I just started seeing `play.sbt.PlayExceptions$UnexpectedException` which is unusual. Checked through a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338684/java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-error-when-running-sbt-t). I still could not resolve the issue with the answers provided there.

```
Error stack is as follows :: 
  [service-gateway] $ compile:run
    [info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/user/Documents/dev/backend_test_project/service-gateway/}root...
    [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.5 ...
    [info] Done updating.

    --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

    [info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

    (Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

    [info] Compiling 5 Scala sources and 5 Java sources to C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\backend_test_project\service-gateway\target\scala-2.12\classes...
    [warn] C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\backend_test_project\service-gateway\app\views\swagger.scala.html:43: method current in object Play is deprecated (since 2.5.0):
    This is a static reference to application, use DI instead
    [warn]             url = "@{s"${current.configuration.getString("swagger.api.basepath")
    [warn]                          ^
    [warn] C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\backend_test_project\service-gateway\app\views\swagger.scala.html:43: method getString in class Configuration is deprecated (sinc
    e 2.6.0): Use get[String] or getAndValidate[String] with reference config entry
    [warn]             url = "@{s"${current.configuration.getString("swagger.api.basepath")
    [warn]                                                ^
    [warn] two warnings found
    [info] C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\backend_test_project\service-gateway\app\ErrorHandler.java: C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\backend_test_project\service-gateway\app\
    ErrorHandler.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [info] C:\Users\user\Documents\dev\backend_test_project\service-gateway\app\ErrorHandler.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:manipulateBytecode for the full output.
    [error] (compile:manipulateBytecode) java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "             "
    [error] application -

    ! @7ff5h00md - Internal server error, for (POST) [/cars/create_car?api_key=33%23kadadji%2323423kadad934340] ->

    play.sbt.PlayExceptions$UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NumberFormatException: For input string: "             "]
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:34)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:27)
            at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:27)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:23)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:50)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:50)
            at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:50)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:73)
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "             "
            at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
            at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:578)
            at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
            at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:230)
            at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:31)
            at com.typesafe.play.sbt.enhancer.PlayEnhancer$$anonfun$bytecodeEnhance$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PlayEnhancer.scala:58)
            at com.typesafe.play.sbt.enhancer.PlayEnhancer$$anonfun$bytecodeEnhance$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PlayEnhancer.scala:48)
            at com.typesafe.play.sbt.enhancer.PlayEnhancer$$anonfun$scopedSettings$2.apply(PlayEnhancer.scala:38)
            at com.typesafe.play.sbt.enhancer.PlayEnhancer$$anonfun$scopedSettings$2.apply(PlayEnhancer.scala:34)
            at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
```

I did not make any changes to my project codes. The versions of the build tools (Maven and SBT) and Java versions are provided below.

```
**I am using Java Version :
C:\Users\user>java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)**

SBT version 
**[service-gateway] $ version
[info] 1.0**

I am also using maven :
**Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)**
```

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information. The issue is related to a POST request here, as the error message indicates: `/cars/create_car`

It seems to me that you are passing an invalid payload somewhere and should look into that. It might be a good idea to add validation to your fields to add a descriptive error message if a numeric field is not what it's supposed to be.

Comment: The same route causing the issue was working perfectly before my computer went off. I fixed the issues relating to the validation errors before this. I have tested all other routes too. The same issue. In fact I decided to visit the http://127.0.0.1:9000/, I still got the same Exception. Checking all other routes made me to conclude that the issue is no where related to the post request.

Answer (score 1):

Met the same issue, i tried delete the files in target folder, start again and worked.